# Using xpath containing whitespace

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, normalize

```
List <WebElement> tableSituacao = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tabela\"]/tbody/tr/td[5][contains(text(),"+situacao+")]"));
```

how to use normalize-space in my case? "situacao" has white spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to handle this with XPath. You can just `.trim()` the string.

```
List <WebElement> tableSituacao = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='tabela']/tbody/tr/td[5][contains(text(),'" + situacao.trim() + "')]"));
```

I would also use `'` inside the XPath instead of escaping the double quotes `\"`. I think it makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the variable `situacao` within the `xpath` you can use the following line of code :

```
List <WebElement> tableSituacao = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='tabela']/tbody/tr/td[5][normalize-space()='" + situacao + "']"));
```

Comment: my problem isn't pass situacao whitin xpath but get this String with white spaces

situacao = "Example" (works)
situacao = "Example Example" (don't work)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
//*[@id=\"tabela\"]/tbody/tr/td[5][normalize-space()='"+situacao+"')]
```

**Note :** This will work if you have left of right spaces in string like `_example_` (consider `_` as space). but if you tend to consider space middle of and string like `example example` then its a complete string it remove space before first *example* text and after last *example* text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes in your xpath expression. Here I suppose that suticao contains the string "Example Example":

```
List <WebElement> tableSituacao 
= driver.findElements(
      By.xpath("//*[@id='tabela']/tbody/tr/td[5][contains(text(),'" + suticao + "')]");
```